# Is any difference between JPG and jpg when i upload a file in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm using Codeigniter for an app, i made a upload section for some pictures, and i set the filetype as jpg and png, and i want to know if I need to put also JPG, PNG, JPEG and jpeg in configuration setting to be sure that Codigniter will upload the pictures.

Comment: Not an answer, but I would anyway suggest to unify case of filenames before saving it, just so that if you ever need to import those files in Windows (or any OS being case-unsensitive for file names), you don't find yourself with file name conflicts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the `allowed_types` setting you only need to put the file types once and they should be lowercase.

For example (taken from there [help guide](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/file_uploading.html))

```
$config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
```

You may also want to add jpeg to that list in case someone if using the .jpeg file extension.

When a file is uploaded it is passed through the `CI_Upload` class (found in system/libraries/Upload.php) this has the function `is_allowed_filetype` that checks for valid file type with the following lines of code:

```
$ext = strtolower(ltrim($this->file_ext, '.'));

if ( ! in_array($ext, $this->allowed_types))
{
    return FALSE;
}
```

It lowercases the file extension of the file uploaded. So the case of the uploaded file does not affect what file types can be uploaded.